# Python - Finding monthly NPV of Credit Card

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running this program:

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2

monthlyPayment = 0.0
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
low = balance / 12.0
high = ((balance * ((1.0 + monthlyInterestRate)**12.0))/12.0)
monthlyPayment = (high+low)/2
while balance != 0:
    newBalance = balance
    for x in range(1, 13):
        lastMonthBalance = newBalance - monthlyPayment
        newBalance = lastMonthBalance + ((monthlyInterestRate) * lastMonthBalance)
        if -0.002 <= newBalance <= 0.002:
            balance = 0

    if newBalance < 0.0:
        low = 0
        high = monthlyPayment
    elif newBalance > 0.0:
        low = monthlyPayment

    monthlyPayment = (low + high) / 2

print "Lowest Payment: %.2f" % monthlyPayment
```

Originally I tried to find the monthly payment that would make my newBalance equal to 0, however due to limits on processing time, I have opted for a less accurate approach.

However, when I change the bounds from -0.2/0.2 to -0.002/0.002 my answer changes from 14578.55 to 29157.09 and I don't understand why?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At a quick glance if interest is both calculated and charged monthly then `monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12` will be an incorrect way to calculate the monthly rate.

Comment: Yes indeed. However this programme is not designed to be correct financially, but rather to teach me how to programme. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not entirely sure why, but by removing the line where low = 0, makes the code work.

The working code is:

```
#Write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. By a fixed monthly payment, we mean a single number which does not change each month, but instead is a constant amount that will be paid each month.

balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18

monthlyPayment = 0.0
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
low = balance / 12.0
high = ((balance * ((1.0 + monthlyInterestRate)**12.0))/12.0)
monthlyPayment = (high+low)/2
while balance != 0:
    newBalance = balance
    for x in range(1, 13):
        lastMonthBalance = newBalance - monthlyPayment
        newBalance = lastMonthBalance + ((monthlyInterestRate) * lastMonthBalance)
        if -0.05 <= newBalance <= 0.05:
            balance = 0

    if newBalance < 0.0:
        high = monthlyPayment
    elif newBalance > 0.0:
        low = monthlyPayment

    monthlyPayment = (low + high) / 2

print "Lowest Payment: %.2f" % monthlyPayment
```

If anyone can explain to me why this happens, I would be very grateful.